# How to connect Azure Web App througt a Hybrid Connection to Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hybrid-connections

I was looking for the way to connect my Azure Web App using a hybrid connection to my On Premise Database server, Oracle Linux.

Any suggestions?
greetings.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Hybrid Connection Manager does not Support for Linux. The Hybrid Connections feature requires a relay agent in the network that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint. The reply agent (HCM) is not supported on anything earlier than Windows Server 2012. Refer to this doc: [Azure App Service Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).

Also, you can vote [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/18948526-hybrid-connection-manager-support-for-linux) for HCM Support for Linux so that Azure App Service Team will receive your feedback and will have a support plan in the future.

It is recommended to [run Oracle Software on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/campaigns/oracle/) which brings scalability, flexibility, security, and performance to your Oracle workloads—while reducing the cost of infrastructure management. You can see the list of [Oracle images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/oracle-considerations).

Comment: please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Nancy. i solved installing the agent on a server running Windows Server 2012 wich is in the same network that Oracle Linux server. i'vd already voted for the HCM suport for linux, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If the reply helps you, you can accept it.:)